# Apply and function a gsub in a lots of columns

Tags: r, function, multiple-columns, apply, gsub

I am kind of new to R and I want to apply the `gsub` function in columns 6 to 12 in my data frame called `x`.  However, I am kind of stuck. I started using:

```
gsub("\\.", "",x[,c(6:12)])
```

But then it returned only a few rows.
Then, I tried to use this:

```
x1<-apply(x,c(6:12),function(x) gsub("\\.", "",x))
```

But I got the following error:

```
Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Also tried this:

```
for (i in x[,c(6:12)]) 
{a<-data.frame(gsub("\\.", "",i))}
```

Does anybody have a tip or a solution?
It would also be great if someone showed me how to use an `apply` function and `for`.

Comment: check `?apply`. Perhaps , you need `x1<-apply(x[,6:12], 2, function(x) gsub("\.", "",x))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not use the Margin argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another solution. It returns all the columns of the original dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
mutate_at(x, 6:12, gsub("\\.", "", .))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution in a data.table way. It worth considering when a table is big and time is a critical factor.

```
library(data.table)     # load library
x = as.data.table(x)    # convert data.frame into data.table
cols = names(x)[6:12]   # define which columns to work with
x[ , (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {gsub("\\.", "", x)}), .SDcols = cols] # replace
x # enjoy results
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the solution using `apply` from the comments, as this one really helped me:

```
x1 <- apply(x[,6:12], 2, function(x) gsub("\\.", "",x))
```